# Horizontal Scrollbar for William chart not working

Tags: android, charts, scrollview, view, horizontalscrollview

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/garbageListView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <com.db.chart.view.LineChartView xmlns:chart="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/linechart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I'm using [WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart) But I put it in the horizontal scroll view because a large amount of data will shrink the chart. but when I put the code above thinking that it will be flexible it isn't working so please helps me to add scroll view!

Comment: bug https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart/issues/45

Comment: add `android:layerType="software"` on `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: IntelliJ Amiya that won't work I think I 've tried it once That didn't give any changes!

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya That's not working!